# How to get Python class attribute by value?

Tags: python, attributes

How to get an object attribute in Python by value, and not by reference? What I mean is that after getting the object attribute and assigning it to a variable, the variable should no track the changes that might happen to the attribute.

Here is an example:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
    def add(self):
        self.array.append(1)
    def getValue(self):
        return self.array

s = SomeClass()
v = s.getValue()
print(v)  # prints [], as it should 
s.add()   # changes the object's attribute
print(v)  # prints [1], because v is tracking s.array
# how to implement a getter that would keep v the value when it was assinged?
```

I could partially solve this using `copy.deepcopy()`, but that does not work universally for all data types (e.g. socket object).

Comment: There's no universal way to do this. Taking your socket example, what would you want to actually happen there? The function returns a new unconnected socket? Then there's no point calling it. The call returns the original socket and replaces the one in the object with a new unconnected socket? Then you've changed the attribute, which it doesn't sound like you want (and it would be unusual for a "get" function to observably modify the object).

Comment: You can't. There is neither "by value" nor "by reference" in Python. Objects *are* things by themselves, and names, attributes, or slots merely point to them. There is no "attribute tracking changes", what you've done is add an item to *the single list object* that is known by *multiple names*. Likewise, copying doesn't "untrack" things, it creates a *new, separate* object. For some things, it doesn't make *sense* to want to copy them: a socket represents a unique thing *external to the program* and copying the representation won't affect the actual, *external* thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have some misunderstanding about how python works.

## Python passes by reference

1. Everything in python is an object. Even primitive data types (eg. `int`, `str`, ...) are.
2. Any variable is always a reference to an object. There is no way to pass only value.

You can try following exercise

```py
a = [1, 2]  # creating new object and assigning it to `a`
b = a       # now both `a` and `b` refer to same object

a.append(3) # we add 3 to the list, `a` and `b` still refer to same object
a is b      # this returns `True` as we compare object to itself

a = [100]   # creating new object and making `a` to refer to it
a is b      # now this is `False`, `b` still refers to the old object
```

## Some objects are immutable

Another python concept is immutability. Immutable objects are those that can never change their value once they are created no matter what. You can only substitute them with different object.

Most common types are:

- immutable: `int`, `str`, `float`, `tuple`, `frozenset`, `bytes`
- mutable: `list`, `dict`, `set`

Passing an immutable object is as close to passing by value as you can get in python. Because you can be sure it does not get affected by anything. When you need to pass mutable object and you want to be sure it's not changed down the line, you can make copy.

Comment: Thanks! I think I originally overlooked the concept of mutable/immutable objects. This explains the best what I referred to as by value and by reference.
Also, it helps a lot to think about passing/returning objects from this perspective and evaluate their effect (e.g. in case of multiple threads with possible race conditions).